# What does the following Oracle error mean: invalid column index

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I got the following error while testing some code:

> SQLException: Invalid column index

What exactly does that mean?

Is there an online document explaining what all the Oracle error codes and statements?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the exact SQL statement that this error threw on? Perhaps include the exact error details, along with the ORA number?

Comment: Oracle error messages: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17766/toc.htm

Comment: Incorrectly declared parameters in the request. Wrong notation.

Comment: sometime you also do the select * from foo_table; this also results in same error

Answer (score 61, accepted):

If that's a SQLException thrown by Java, it's most likely because you are trying to get or set a value from a ResultSet, but the index you are using isn't within the range.

For example, you might be trying to get the column at index 3 from the result set, but you only have two columns being returned from the SQL query.

Comment: In my case, I was using JayDeBeApi (a Java wrapper in python), and passing query params as sequential arguments instead of a single tuple. It should be `cursor.execute(query, (arg1, arg2))`, not `cursor.execute(query, arg1, arg2)`. The pyodbc library allows either form, and I had gotten used to the latter, but the DB API specifies only the former, so that's the one I'll use from now on for consistency across library implementations.

Comment: In my case I was having a MyBatis mapper with `${columnName}` in place of `#{columnName}`

Answer (score 12):

It sounds like you're trying to `SELECT` a column that doesn't exist.

Perhaps you're trying to `ORDER BY` a column that doesn't exist?

Any typos in your SQL statement?

Answer (score 9):

Using Spring's SimpleJdbcTemplate, I got it when I tried to do this:

```
String sqlString = "select pwy_code from approver where university_id = '123'";
List<Map<String, Object>> rows = getSimpleJdbcTemplate().queryForList(sqlString, uniId);
```

- I had an argument to queryForList that didn't correspond to a question mark in the SQL.  The first line should have been:

  ```
  String sqlString = "select pwy_code from approver where university_id = ?";
  ```

Comment: That was the case for me. JdbcTemplate could have a better message for that exception.

Answer (score 8):

I also got this type error, problem is wrong usage of parameters to statement like, Let's say  you have a query like this

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYE E WHERE E.ID = ?
```

and for the preparedStatement object (JDBC) if you set the parameters like

```
preparedStatement.setXXX(1,value);
preparedStatement.setXXX(2,value)
```

then it  results  in       `SQLException: Invalid column index`

So, I removed that second parameter setting to prepared statement then problem solved

Answer (score 7):

**Just try this fix, as I faced your error:**

Remove the single quotation marks around your question mark, which means, if you used your reserved parameters like ('?','?','?')  you should make it look like this:

```
(?,?,?)
```

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem using a prepared statement. I didn't add enough "?" for the "VALUES"   My eclipse had crashed after I did add the proper amount, and lost those changes. But that didn't occur to me to be the error until I started combing through the SQL as p.campbell suggested.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem when using Spring Security 3.1.0. and Oracle 11G.  I was using the following query and getting the invalid column index error:

```
<security:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
                users-by-username-query="SELECT A.user_name AS username, A.password AS password FROM MB_REG_USER A where A.user_name=lower(?)"
```

It turns out that I needed to add: "1 as enabled" to the query:

```
<security:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource" users-by-username query="SELECT A.user_name AS username, A.password AS password, 1 as enabled FROM MB_REG_USER A where A.user_name=lower(?)"
```

Everything worked after that.  I believe this could be a bug in the Spring JDBC core package...

Answer (score 2):

the final sql statement is something like:

```
select col_1 from table_X where col_2 = 'abcd';
```

i run this inside my SQL IDE and everything is ok.

Next, i try to build this statement with java:

```
String queryString= "select col_1 from table_X where col_2 = '?';";
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(queryString);
stmt.setString(1, "abcd"); //raises java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index
```

Although the sql statement (the first one, ran against the database) contains quotes around string values, and also finishes with a semicolumn, the string that i pass to the PreparedStatement should not contain quotes around the wildcard character ?, nor should it finish with semicolumn.

i just removed the characters that appear on white background

`"select col_1 from table_X where col_2 =` **'** `?` **' ;** `";`

to obtain

```
"select col_1 from table_X where col_2 = ?";
```

(i found the solution here: https://coderanch.com/t/424689/databases/java-sql-SQLException-Invalid-column)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in one legacy application that create prepared statement dynamically.

```
String firstName;
StringBuilder query =new StringBuilder("select id, name from employee where country_Code=1");
query.append("and  name like '");
query.append(firstName + "' ");
query.append("and ssn=?");
PreparedStatement preparedStatement =new prepareStatement(query.toString());
```

when it try to set value for ssn, it was giving invalid column index error, and finally found out that it is caused by firstName having ' within; that disturb the syntax.