# Intermittently getting "sqlexception invalid column index"

Tags: java, oracle, tomcat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the following Oracle error mean: invalid column index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5969081/what-does-the-following-oracle-error-mean-invalid-column-index)

I am running tomcat 7 with tomcat jdbc connection pool and oracle database. I am intermittently seeing "sqlexception invalid column index" exception when running certain queries. It usually happens when same query is run a lots of time within a very short amount of time.

Comment: Could this be a thread-safety issue?  Are you reusing something from old requests?

Comment: Consider posting your SQL query and the code where you experience this error.

Comment: The problem occurs in random places with different pieces of code and different queries. When those same queries are executed over longer period of time everything works fine, problem occurs when they run lots of times within shorter period