# Parsing subfields in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following table

```
DRIVER_GID              DRIVER_REFNUM_QUAL_GID  

SDL2/C001.100000        SDL2.486900 CURRENT DISTRICT 
SDL2/C001.100000        SDL2.486900 PERMANENT DISTRICT 
SDL2/C001.100000000     SDL2.486900 CURRENT DISTRICT  
SDL2/C001.100000000     SDL2.486900 PERMANENT DISTRICT 
SDL2.600119036          SDL2.436001 CURRENT DISTRICT  
SDL2.600119036          SDL2.436001 PERMANENT DISTRICT
```

I need to extract the numeric value after the string "SDL2." from DRIVER_REFNUM_QUAL_GID column. could anyone please recommend a query.

Comment: See http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7938/SQL-User-Defined-Function-to-Parse-a-Delimited-Str for a solution that should work.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Is the number after "SDL." always starting at position 6 and 6 characters wide? If so, a simple `substr(driver_refnum_qual_gid, 6, 6)` will extract the string you want.

Comment: We are using Oracle, "SDL" is not always starting at 6th position, the position may change. But "." is constant and after "." there should be a numeric value followed by space and Current or Permanent district words.

Comment: The fact that you need to do this shows that you probably have a very bad data design. Store the numeric value separately.

Comment: Do the numbers you want to extract always have 6 digits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `regexp_substr` function of **`ORACLE`**:

```
select regexp_substr(DRIVER_REFNUM_QUAL_GID, '[[:digit:]]{6}') from YOURTABLE
```

This will extract adjacent 6 digits from DRIVER_REFNUM_QUAL_GID column of your yourtable.

If you prefer to extract all digits following period then use the following code:

```
select regexp_substr(DRIVER_REFNUM_QUAL_GID, '(\.)([[:digit:]]+)',1,1,'i',2) from YOURTABLE
```

To eliminate `NULLS`, you can use `NVL` function.

For example,

```
select NVL(regexp_substr(DRIVER_REFNUM_QUAL_GID, '(\.)([[:digit:]]+)',1,1,'i',2),999999) from YOURTABLE
```

So, if the result of the `regexp_substr` function is `NULL`, the result will be `999999`.

Comment: Tried: select regexp_replace(DRIVER_REFNUM_QUAL_GID, '[^[:digit:]]') from DRIVER_REFNUM ## Result:  java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index, i think we are near let me know the exact sql

Comment: This doesn't allow for a variable number of digits following the dot.

Comment: @bonsvr I got invalid column index error while executing your query

Comment: SQL part is working with no problem, it seems a Java error. Check this [link] : (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5969081/what-does-the-following-oracle-error-mean-invalid-column-index)

Comment: I was using a html sql editor, when i changed my editor it was working fine. Can you also send me the sql which does not have null or empty values in the resultset

Answer (score 0):

Considering you only need numbers after `SDL2.` and considering that the number of digits could go up to a max of 20 digits, you can use something like-

`select  REGEXP_SUBSTR('SDL2.486900 CURRENT DISTRICT',  '[[:digit:]]{2,20}') numval from dual;`

You can edit the number `20` to suit your needs.

So it would look like-

`select REGEXP_SUBSTR(DRIVER_REFNUM_QUAL_GID,'[[:digit:]]{2,20}') from your_table;`

Comment: I would like to have only 486900, can you please send me the sql