# ResultSet Invalid column index

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset, sqlexception

I have this error: Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index, when I want to get the emails form the resultSet in order to send an emails by looping in the search result and get one email by one.

```
public List<UserDto> getEmail() {
    
    Connection connection = null;
    
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    
    ResultSet searchResultSet = null;
    
    try {
    
        connection = getConnection();
    
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(
                        "SELECT EMAIL FROM USER WHERE USER.U_SEQ IN ('1','650')");
                
        searchResultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
    
        return getEmail(searchResultSet);
    
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } finally {
        try {
            preparedStatement.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}


private List<UserDto> getEmail(ResultSet searchResultSet) throws SQLException {
    List<UserDto> result = new ArrayList<UserDto >();

    UserDto userDto = null;
    int index = 1;
    while (searchResultSet.next()) {
        userDto = new UserDto();

        userDto .setEmailAddress(searchResultSet.getString(index));
        result.add(userDto);
        index++;
     }
     return result;
}
```

second class that I call the getEmail method:

```
Delegate delegate = new Delegate();

UserDto userDto = new UserDto();

List<UserDto> users = delegate.getEmail();

delegate.sendNotification("****", "****", users .toString(), "", "",
                   "", body);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the following Oracle error mean: invalid column index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5969081/what-does-the-following-oracle-error-mean-invalid-column-index)

Comment: did you try with index = 0??

Comment: @Sobhan no, those indexes are 1-based, not 0-based. See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getString(int))

Comment: It looks like you're increasing `index` with every record you read. If there are more results than columns you will get this error.

Comment: Why are you doing  `index++;` inside your loop? That line makes no sense. You always want to select the first and only column your SQL would return

Comment: why not use `searchResultSet.getString("EMAIL")` ?

Comment: Shouldn't the loop check for searchResultSet.hasNext(), and inside the loop retrieve the record by calling searchResultSet.next()?

Answer (score 4):

The failure is in getEmail(ResultSet searchResultSet) function.

Why are you increasing the index value?

The index variable is the column index, not row index.

You loop through the result set with the .next() in your while cycle.

Keep index value on 1, and never change it.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments, regarding looping the index because I have several rows of emails that I want one by one to send an email for the users. I change it to 1 now but it not gives me any result. Any help!!!!

Comment: @uma Did you change your code something like: `userDto .setEmailAddress(searchResultSet.getString(1));` and did remove the `index++` row?
Or `..searchResultSet.getString("EMAIL")...` should work also.

Comment: I remove index++ already. I trid both but no result.

Comment: @uma Debugging may will be the best way to find problem quickly.

Comment: It works with me like this    userDto.setEmailAddress(searchResultSet.getString(1));